# Find the roots of the equation - $z^2 +12jz+64 = 0$

Tags: roots, quadratics

Just needing a little guidance. This is what I've done so far and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Using quadratic formula:

$$z^2+12jz+64=0$$

$$ z= \frac{-12j ±\sqrt{(12j^2-4\times1\times64)}}{2\times1}=\\
-12j ±\frac{\sqrt{3072}}{2}=\\
-12j ±\frac{2\sqrt{1536}}{2}=\\
-12j±\sqrt{1536}.$$

Is this right way to go about it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did the $j$ inside the square root go?

Comment: Is $\;j=i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ ? Also, you had to divide by two in the last step, so you get $\;12i/2=6i\;$

Comment: Ah so how do you incorperate the square root 1?

Comment: welcome to MSE, please use  [MathJAx](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) to get a good formate of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\;j=i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ :

$$z^2+12iz+64=0\implies \Delta=b^2-4ac=-144-256=-400=(20i)^2\implies$$

$$z_{1,2}=\frac{-12i\pm20i}{2}=\begin{cases}-16i\\{}\\\;\;\;\,4i\end{cases}$$

Comment: I'm not aware, but have you seen $j$ being used anywhere instead of $i$ (in some textbook or paper)?

Comment: Yeah i have, just with the i thing. If i = square root -1 thats not calculatable, how did you get to -144, obviously 12 square then multiplied by -1?

Comment: In some parts of physics it is used $\;j^2=-1\;$ , like in electricity.

Comment: @User1111111 What do you mean by " If i = square root -1 thats not calculatable" ? And yes: $\;(12i)^2=-144\;$